# Eclipse plugin to roll up if and for?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm at university, and we were taught to use notepad to programme java to start with. I moved onto notepad++ and quickly onto eclipse.
In notepad++, i could roll up (plus minus sign) if statements or for loop as well as methods and classes. I wondered if there is a plugin for eclipse that allows me to do the same?

Also, are there any essential plugins i should be using with eclipse? I'm rather new to programming.

Thanks in advance

Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Eclipse you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to mark the surrounding block to the current block
(and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to narrow down again).

Then <kbd>←</kbd> will place you at the beginning of the block, and <kbd>→</kbd> at the end.

(Untested, from memory, but VERY handy).

Comment: thats handy! thanks.
sadly the question still remains unanswered

Comment: seems there is no way currently of doing this. oh well

Comment: In addition, you can jump to the matching brace using Ctrl+Shift+P.

Comment: I may have misunderstood you.  Is this a matter of collapsing and uncollapsing lines similar to what you can do with the import statements?

Answer (score 7):

The eclipse [Coffee-Bytes Code Folding Plug-in](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-269.html) (which is [mentioned by htw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764034/eclipse-plugin-to-roll-up-if-and-for/764047#764047)) is no longer available.

[Starting with release 3.0, Eclipse allows folding in its text editor](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Folding-in-Eclipse-Text-Editors/folding.html), and that include code folding for classes, comments, imports, but not for if or loop structures.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecjbuild/3-codefolding.gif))</sub>

A simple double click at the beginning or end of a block (`{`) is enough to highlight the all block.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I didn't notice—thanks for the heads up!

Comment: darn, that looked like the exact thing i was looking for! :(